# Python: Importing multiple txt files and converting them into lists

Tags: python

I have multiple .txt files for my python project. All are lists of strings seperated by lines. Previously, I have imported each txt file and converted them into lists individually using

```
 with open('general_responses.txt') as f:
     general_responses = f.read().splitlines()
```

But, I want to automoate this using a for loop in order to speed up the process so that I can more easily add response lists to my project. So, this is the code I currently have, not that it works...

```
final_files = ['general_responses.txt', 'cat_responses.txt', 'dog_responses.txt']
for word in final_files:
    with open(word) as f:
        word = word[:-4]
        word = f.read().splitlines()
```

so when I run

```
print (general_responses)
```

my script should print out a list of strings from the txt file general_responses.txt

However, this does not work. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

for example, general_responses.txt would contain something along the lines of:

```
hi i'm fred
whats up
how are you doing today?
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to collect the result of each file in a separate list (here called `lines`):

```
final_files = ['general_responses.txt', 'cat_responses.txt', 'dog_responses.txt']
lines = []
for filename in final_files:
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines.extend(f.read().splitlines())
```